# How to unbind a key binding in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I have a habit of hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in ST2. However this invokes the transpose function. I could map the `new_file` command to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but is it possible to disable the command completely via user keymap file. My search suggested adding this to user keymap.

```
[ { "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "unbound" } ]
```

Is the "unbound" an officially endorsed way of disabling a shortcut?

Comment: The official documentation is here: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html As of this writing, it makes no mention of unbinding.

Comment: thanks I really needed that `super+forward_slash` unbound! I use it to search in the menu bar in all apps.

Answer (score 26):

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "noop" }`

Binding a key to a no-operation or anything which wouldn't carry a command behavior, such as "hello", should work.

This would also keep the body of the binding if you change your mind in the future.

Comment: I prefer this as it's a little more explicit than just binding the keys to nothing.

Answer (score 23):

I have never see or read any *official* documentation about the `unbound` command, but it works. Another option would be removing the `command` attribute.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+t"] }
```

This will also *unbound* a key binding.

Comment: If I type any gibberish instead of "unbound", it has the same effect. I'm curious about the 'correct' way of doing it... Do you have a documented / official source for your second method? I don't think it works.

Comment: This is mentioned on the Sublime UserEcho forum: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/89378-support-unbinding-of-keys/

Comment: It seems as though if a key combo is defined in my default keybindings, but I want to unbind it in my user bindings, omitting "command" does not work, but setting "command": "unbound" does.

Comment: I hit ctrl+T too many times when I want to 'redo', completely destroying the 'redo-history', so I bound this: { "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "redo_or_repeat" }

Comment: Yep, in the user bindings only setting command to unbound works for me. Simply omitting the command does no change.

Comment: At least in my Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS X, this does not seem to work, I get an error about not being able to parse the key binding. Mapping to `"command": "unbound"` does work.

Comment: +1 Worked for me to remove a keybinding defined in the default keybindings file from the user keybindings file. Using Sublime Text 3 build 3095 (Dev Channel),OSX 10.10.4. The "command": "unbound" or "command": "noop" solution was swallowing the shortcut used for an external application (clipboard manager)

Answer (score 15):

Also, if you're looking to undo a shortcut that was overridden by a plugin (I'm looking at you, "Terminal"):

1. find your previous shortcut in **Preferences -> Key Bindings (Default)**
2. Copy the line (e.g. `{ "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "reopen_last_file" }`)
3. Open  **Preferences -> Key Bindings (User)**
4. Add the the line in there (if the file is empty, it add `[` and `]` before the line, since it's an array of commands)

Comment: +1 for the Terminal diss. Side note, it's `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "reopen_last_file" }` for Windows users.

Comment: Came here exactly for the same reason (Terminal). So there is no convenient way to get the original shortcut back other than copying it? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

Actually this [post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13303#p51851) did help me with my issue when using ST3 on mac.  Using the Package Resource Viewer you can edit the default keyboard shortcuts (Default (OSX).sublime-keymap) and delete the lines that you don't want.  After doing that ST3 will no longer capture your system-wide hotkeys.

Answer (score 5):

The [Path Tools](https://github.com/pjdietz/sublime-path-tools) package includes [key bindings](https://github.com/pjdietz/sublime-path-tools/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap) that override default Sublime key bindings which I use often, specifically: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

On a Mac, I was able to override all of the default bindings of the Path Tools package by placing a blank file here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Path Tools/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap
```

I wish Sublime package installation warned users when a package includes key-bindings which will override current or default key bindings.

Comment: Yay! The Path Tools author (pjdietz) has since removed the conflicting key bindings:
https://github.com/pjdietz/sublime-path-tools/commit/8208974e0410aac4221b0cb4f6b0e63a70477e28
https://github.com/pjdietz/sublime-path-tools/commit/ff4674d95b3664018fc2d924f95dc384293be27e
https://github.com/pjdietz/sublime-path-tools/commit/e8e7ad9fc255fa945f78cd11e780ed1b95ace656?diff=split

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to overwrite the default bindings of installed packages by creating a custom default bindings file.

For example I want ctrl-T to transpose, so I have modified default bindings for CTags:

- Copy `c:\Users\USER\appdata\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\CTags.CTags.sublime-package` to `tmp.zip`
- From the zip file extract `Default.sublime-keymap` to `c:\Users\USER\appdata\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\CTags\`
- Modify or remove the binding from this file.

If the package is updated the custom default binding file is kept, so your bindings are kept and any new bindings will have to be updated manually.

Comment: A quick and convenient way to do this is using the `PackageResourceViewer` package. Run command "open resource" then select the guilty package then open the keymap file and edit it as you wish. This avoids having to navigate to the correct file.